# Managing ModBus protocol in C# using serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application, modbus

I am using [Modbus by sontx](https://bitbucket.org/sontx/dotnet-utils/src/master/Code4Bugs.Utils/IO/Modbus/) library in `C#`. I want to separate write and read separately. Below is the code

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM16", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var error = "06";
        string key = "0";
        try
        {
            
            //serial port settings and opening it
            serialPort.Open();

            var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
            stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            // send request and waiting for response
            // the request needs: slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount            
            var responseBytes = stream.RequestFunc3(slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount);

            // extract the content part (the most important in the response)
            var data = responseBytes.ToResponseFunc3().Data;

            var finalData = floatArray(data);


            //var result = data.Where(r => r > 0).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray();
             dict = finalData.Select((b, i) => (value: b, index: i)) // convert bytes to sequence of (byte value, index)
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.index.ToString(), x => x.value.ToString());

            serialPort.Close();

            return dict;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            serialPort.Close();
            if (e is DataCorruptedException)
            {
                BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("checksum is failed", e);
                dict.Add(key, error);
                
            }
            else if (e is EmptyResponsedException)
            {
                BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("request timeout", e);
                dict.Add(key, error);
            }
            else if (e is MissingDataException)
            {
                BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("Missing response bytes", e);
                dict.Add(key, error);
            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(key, error);
            }
            
            
            return dict;
        }        
                   
    }
 public static float[] floatArray(byte[] data)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        float[] dataFloats =
            data.GroupBy(x => offset++ / 4) // group by 4. 0/4 = 0, 1/4 = 0, 2/4 = 0, 3/4 = 0 and 4/4 = 1 etc.
                                            // Need to reverse the bytes to make them evaluate to 2.4
            .Select(x => BitConverter.ToSingle(x.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray(), 0))
            .ToArray();

        return dataFloats;
    }
```

The above code works perfectly alright for a single request. But I want to run continuously. i.e. I want to send and receive the request separately. I have a `DataReceivedHandler` in which I want to read the data from the port. For this, I have changed my code

```
 public static SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM16", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

 public ModBusEngine()
    {
        
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        port.Open();            
       
    }
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       
       // here I want to read only
       
    }
```

As far as I know, using this library you will send the request and wait for a response at the same time. The purpose to write and read separately is to manage the read response in a data handler.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. If you want to keep reading data just keep the port open and send multiple requests in a loop. Modbus is not intended to send queries and listen for answers separately. If you want to do that it's quite likely you'll have to modify the library or write your own.

Comment: Just to be sure this is where I got lost: you equate run continuously with send queries and listen for replies separately, how does that make sense?

Comment: You need a waitone so after sending you wait for the receive before sending second message.  See socket example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example